# Draggable content on MapOverlay in windows phone 8 and new map control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, here-api

The new Nokia map control in windows Phone 8 is not letting me drag a control that i've added to a MapOverlay and to a mapLayer added to a map. I'm ussing Behavior from Interactivity dll. The thing is that i can tap on the pin, i can detect dragging events, but the map keeps panning. Thanks in advance!
EDIT:

When I try to drag the cusom pin over the map, the map moves with the dragging. What would be the correct way to implement Dragging of a child control in the new Nokia Map?

Comment: I have experience doing this but and CAN help you but you need to format your question appropriately. Please provide the "Question/Code/Error OR Problem" format to your post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new Map control from nokia does not supports dragging of an element. But Nokia's developers specifies a workaround in the following link http://www.slideshare.net/nokia-developer/lumia-app-labs-here-maps-and-location-apis-for-windows-phone